# Google Earth Closing Suddenly in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, google-earth

Google Earth closing Suddenly in Ubuntu. I can't figure out why it is happening..but the Err log is...

```
[0518/102428:ERROR:net_util.cc(2195)] Not implemented reached in bool net::HaveOnlyLoopbackAddresses()
[0518/102428:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102433:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0518/102433:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0518/102438:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0518/102439:ERROR:nss_ocsp.cc(581)] No URLRequestContext for OCSP handler.
[0518/102440:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1594)] Messed up entry found.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102442:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102444:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102456:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
[0518/102457:WARNING:backend_impl.cc(1875)] Destroying invalid entry.
Another crash happened while handling crash!
```

Help...Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, ie Google Earth started normally and after a few seconds crashing.
I ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure google-earth
```

and this helped me to solve it.

It will reset the installation and probably allow a previously working installation to restart normally.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure google-earth-stable` here. `google-earth` just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the Google Earth 32bit software and it fixed it for me.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I was talking about Google Earth 32 bits software

Comment: oh I see, thanks. Could you edit again and add the exact command needed?